# Create a unique id for each parent child path - Python

Tags: python, parent-child, genealogy

I'm currently learning python and I'm stuck to resolve a problem.
I have a simple genealogy table (2 columns: parent_id, child_id), I would like to create a raw for each path and create a unique ID (keep the same ID if last child is the same).
Something like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiaMy.png)
I tried several methods unsuccessfully.
Do you have some ideas?
Thank you

Comment: what does you mean "create a raw" ?  you can put this into a dataframe or a dict on python.

Comment: I don't if it's the good term, I would like to do a table like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiaMy.png

Answer (score 0):

You could put this into a dataframe or a dictionary.

Here is the dataframe example:

```py
import io
import pandas as pd


# example dable
x = '''
parent, child 1, child 2, child 3, child 4, id
a, b, c, d, e, Id1  
g, f, e, , , Id1
h, i, j, k, , Id2
i, j, m, k, , Id2
'''

# data into a dataframe
data = io.StringIO(x)
df = pd.read_csv(data, sep=', ')

df
```

which returns this:

[image]